# element subset for adjacency matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, notation

I am trying to create an element of a matrix that is a subset of a larger matrix. However, I am told that my subscripts do not match. I wanted other people's opinion as to what I am doing wrong and how to produce mathematical notation that does what I am intending. In particular, they are saying you can't use l and m as subscripts since I am using i, and j for my element. See below.

$c_{ij}$ is given by:  \begin{equation}
c_{ij} = \left \{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 &   \mbox{if a contact relationship (link) exists between individual i and another individual j } \\
 0,  &  \mbox{ otherwise }\\
\end{array}
\right. . \end{equation}

The elements of the similarity matrix $\mathbf{C}$ are divided up into their sub-similarity matrices based on their having the same indicator variable level.

\begin{equation}
  M_{ij} = \left \{
 \begin{array}{ll}
1 &  \mbox{if } k_i = k_j = 0 \\
-1 &  \mbox{if } k_i = k_j = 1 \\
  0,   \mbox{ otherwise}  \\
\end{array}
\right. . \end{equation}

Thus, $c_{lm}^{(0)}$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
c_{lm}^{(0)} = \left \{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 &   \mbox{if } c_{ij}M_{ij}  = 1    \\
      0 & \mbox{if }  M_{ij} = 1  \mbox{ and } c_{ij}M_{ij} \neq 1 \\
\end{array}
\right. ,  \end{equation}

and $\mathbf{C}^{(0)} = [c_{lm}^{(0)}]_{\delta \times \delta}$, where $\delta = \mid \mathfrak{D}^0 \mid$

What I am thinking might work instead is:  Let $\mathfrak{D}^{(0)}$ be the set of individuals that have covariate level zero ($k_i = 0$).  Let $\mathfrak{D}^{(1)}$, be the set of individuals that have covariate level one ($k_i = 1$), where $\mathfrak{D}^{(1)}  =  \mathfrak{D}  \setminus \mathfrak{D}^{(0)}$.

\begin{equation}
 Q^{(0)}_{ij} =   \left \{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 &   \mbox{if } c_{ij}M_{ij}  = 1    \\
      0 & \mbox{if }  M_{ij} = 1  \mbox{ and } c_{ij}M_{ij} \neq 1 \\
      -1 & \mbox{otherwise} \\
  \end{array}
\right. ,  \end{equation}

ok, here is a **modification**

\begin{equation}
 q^{(0)}_{ij} =   \left \{
\begin{array}{ll}
      c_{ij} &   \mbox{ if } k_i  = 0   \\
      -1 & \mbox{ if } k_i  = 1  \\
  \end{array}
\right. ,  \end{equation}

We obtain matrices $Q^{(0)} = \left[q^{(0)}_{ij}\right]_{N \times N}$, and $Q^{(1)} = \left[q^{(1)}_{ij}\right]_{N \times N} $.

Let \begin{equation} C^{(0)}  =  \left[c_{ij}^{(0)}\right]_{\delta \times \delta} = Q^{(0)} \left(\mathfrak{D}^{(1)} \right), \end{equation} where  $Q^{(0)} \left(\mathfrak{D}^{(1)} \right)$  is the matrix with rows and columns from the set $\mathfrak{D}^{(1)}$ removed and $\delta = \mid \mathfrak{D}^0 \mid$.

Comment: What are $k_i$? Also, yes, it makes no sense to write the definition of $c^{(0)}_{lm}$ with no reference to $l$ and $m$. It is like defining $f(x) = y^3 - z$. If the definition of $f(x)$ does not involve $x$, then $f(x)$ is constant (with value $y^3 - z$, whatever $y$ and $z$ may be). But your definition of $C^{(0)}$ is not even that, because it is not well defined. *Which* $c_{ij}$ and $M_{ij}$ are referred to in the definiton of $C^{(0)}$? That is not clear from the context. Are those supposed to be $c_{lm}$ and $M_{lm}$?

Comment: @M. Vinay, thank you, $k_i$ and  $k_j$ are levels of covariate. Also both $C$ and $C^{(0)}$ are intended to be a matrix. I was trying to create a subset of the elements that satisfy my condition and was using l and m to represent an element $c_{lm}$ of this matrix. Does definition $Q_{ij}^{(0)}$ work.

Comment: Perhaps you could actually show a small example with matrices $C$ and $M$, and what you want $C^{(0)}$ to be. Then it would be possible to generalize from that.

Comment: @M.Vinay,  thanks for your help. I have provided description of another approach that might work. See what you think. It is a more top-down approach (i.e. starting with full matrix) as opposed to my original "bottom-up" attempt. If this does work, I will provide an example